# Python unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing

Hi i want to passed my unit test, but i do not know how
Can you help me please
I do not how to write code and unit test

I have advice from forum but my skills for programing my skills is minimalist

Instead writing a bunch of code that I will probably get wrong (good reason to test), I would build dictionary2 (terrible name) from dictionary (equally terrible name). Can do it in 1 line of Python code.

Your example is not written correctly for testing (or for being useful). coding() and decoding() should not print, they should return the translated string. Once modified, you test can call them with a string and compare the returned string against the expected result.

selection() will be difficult to test because it calls input(). You need to replace the existing function with one that returns strings provided by the test. I don't see this as being worth the effort.

You should modify the example.py module so it doesn't run any code when imported. Write a main() function, and only call this function if **name** == "**main**

```
dictionary={'A':'.-', 'B':'-...',
            'C':'-.-.', 'D':'-..', 'E':'.','F':'..-.', 'G':'--.', 'H':'....',
            'I':'..', 'J':'.---', 'K':'-.-','L':'.-..', 'M':'--', 'N':'-.',
            'O':'---', 'P':'.--.', 'Q':'--.-','R':'.-.', 'S':'...', 'T':'-',
            'U':'..-', 'V':'...-', 'W':'.--','X':'-..-', 'Y':'-.--', 'Z':'--..',}
 
dictionary2={'.-':'A','-...':'B','-.-.':'C','-..':'D', '.':'E','..-.':'F','--.':'G','....':'H',
             '..':'I','.---':'J', '-.-':'K','.-..':'L', '--':'M', '-.':'N',
             '---':'O', '.--.':'P', '--.-':'Q','.-.':'R', '...':'S', '-':'T',
             '..-':'U', '...-':'V', '.--':'W','-..-':'X', '-.--':'Y', '--..':'Z',}
 
 
def coding(s):
    void=" "
    for i in s: #indexování
        if i != ' ':
            void+=dictionary[i]+" "
        else:
            void += ' '
 
    print(void)
 
     
def decoding(s):
    void = ""
    splitstring = a.split(" ") #rozdělení podle mezer
    for i in splitstring: #indexování
            void += dictionary2[i]
    print(void)
     
def selection(f):
     f=int(input("1. Z ČEŠTINY DO MORSEOVKY || 2. Z MORESOVKY DO ČEŠTINY ")) # menu
     return f
 
c = 1
d = 0
while(c!="0"):
    d =selection(d)
    a=input("ZADEJ TEXT NA ŠIFROVÁNÍ: ")
    a=a.upper()
 
    startUp="" # nevyužívá se ale bez ní program nelze spustit
 
 
 
 
    if d==1: # šifrování
        coding(a)
 
 
 
    else: # dešifrování
        decoding(a)
 
   
    c = input(("POKUD CHCTE PROGRAM UKONČIT, ZADEJTE 0 || PRO POKRAČOVÁNÍ ZADEJTE LIBOVOLNÝ ZNAK : "))
```

```
from example import coding
from example import decoding
from example import selection
from example import a
 
import pytest
 
def test_coding():
    #test coding for letters A-Z
    assert test_coding('A') == '.-'
    assert test_coding('B') == '-...'
    assert test_coding('C') == '-.-.'
    assert test_coding('D') == '-..'
    assert test_coding('E') == '.'
    assert test_coding('F') == '..-.' 
    assert test_coding('G') == '--.'
    assert test_coding('H') == '....'
    assert test_coding('I') == '..'
    assert test_coding('J') == '.---'
    assert test_coding('K') == '-.-'
    assert test_coding('L') == '.-..'
    assert test_coding('M') == '--'
    assert test_coding('N') == '-.'
    assert test_coding('O') == '---'
    assert test_coding('P') == '.--.'
    assert test_coding('Q') == '--.-'
    assert test_coding('R') == '.-.'
    assert test_coding('S') == '...'
    assert test_coding('T') == '-'
    assert test_coding('U') == '..-'
    assert test_coding('V') == '...-'
    assert test_coding('W') == '.--'
    assert test_coding('X') == '-..-'
    assert test_coding('Y') == '-.--'
    assert test_coding('Z') == '--..'
 
    # test typeerror
    with pytest.raises(TypeError):
        test_coding(4)
        test_coding(True)
        test_coding("r")
         
 
     
 
     
def test_decoding() :
    #test decoding for letters A-Z
    assert test_decoding('.-') == 'A'
    assert test_decoding('-...') == 'B'
    assert test_decoding('-.-.') == 'C'
    assert test_decoding('-..') == 'D'
    assert test_decoding('.') == 'E'
    assert test_decoding('..-.') == 'F'
    assert test_decoding('--.') == 'G'
    assert test_decoding('....') == 'H'
    assert test_decoding('..') == 'I'
    assert test_decoding('---') == 'J'
    assert test_decoding('-.-') == 'K'
    assert test_decoding('.-..') == 'L'
    assert test_decoding('--') == 'M'
    assert test_decoding('-.') == 'N'
    assert test_decoding('---') == 'O'
    assert test_decoding('.--.') == 'P'
    assert test_decoding('--.-') == 'Q'
    assert test_decoding('.-.') == 'R'
    assert test_decoding('...') == 'S'
    assert test_decoding('-') == 'T'
    assert test_decoding('..-') == 'U'
    assert test_decoding('...-') == 'V'
    assert test_decoding('.--') == 'W'
    assert test_decoding('-..-') == 'X'
    assert test_decoding('-.--') == 'Y'
    assert test_decoding('--..') == 'Z'
 
def test_selection():
    assert test_selection(1) == test_coding(a)
```

I do not know how to passed unit test

Comment: In all your test functions why are you recursively calling the test function rather than the function you want to test?  For instance, function test_coding erroneously calls function test_coding.

Comment: i do not how to test